# Long-lived command line app only writing to file once with fs.createWriteStream

Tags: node.js, fs

Super annoying problem here. Only the first write call on a `fs.createWriteStream` is working as expected.

I have this code

```
const errStrmPath = global.testStderrStrmPath = path.resolve(projRoot + '/suman/logs/test-stderr.log');
const strm = global.testStderrStrm = fs.createWriteStream(errStrmPath, {flags: 'w'});

global._writeTestError = function () {
    global.checkTestErrorLog = true;
    strm.write.apply(strm, arguments);
};

global._writeTestError('abc');
global._writeTestError('efg');
global._writeTestError('hij');
```

as it stands, it only writes to the log file once. So 'abc' shows up in the file, but 'efg' and 'hij' do not show up. This is a long-lived program, that only exits after some asynchronous actions are taken, why would only the first write to the file happen?

Anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I can accomplish what I want using sync methods, but this is much less ideal.

if I change the implementation of `global._writeTestError` from this

```
global._writeTestError = function () {
    global.checkTestErrorLog = true;
    strm.write.apply(strm, arguments); // async
};
```

to this

```
global._writeTestError = function (data) {
    global.checkTestErrorLog = true;
    fs.appendFileSync(errStrmPath, data); //now sync
};
```

withe the sync method, everything works as expected. It's very frustrating to not be able to use fs.createWriteStream, and force it to flush it's contents before calling process.exit(). Is there a way to force the stream to flush all data before exiting?